# how to connect MS Access database with matlab (transfer data from GUI and save in database )

Tags: database, matlab, user-interface, ms-access-2010

Hello ppl I am trying to work with databases and I am new to Matlab.
I want to manipulate databeses created in MS Access but I don't know(I hope find a way to enter data from GUI (this GUI created using matlab ) and save in database)
I've designed the user interface in MATLAB, and create a database in MS Access
The problem I do not know how I connect between the database and MATLAB 
I find some code to how connect between it.

```
dbpath = ['C:\Users\Esra\Documents\Esra.accdb'];
conurl = [['jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ='] dbpath];
con = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver', conurl);
```

**I hope find good code or book about this .**

**final , i don not know if it is the correct place to my question or not , if not ,please put my question in correct place**

Answer (score 1):

You need to run SQL queries on the database; you can do this with [`database.fetch`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/database/ug/database.fetch.html) (and a few other friends).

The example query from the docs:

```
conn = database('dbtoolboxdemo','','');
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray')
results = fetch(conn, 'select productdescription from producttable')

% Not in the example in the docs: this syntax, which I prefer, is also supported
results = conn.fetch('select productdescription from producttable');
```

Note that you will also need to know how to write SQL. For that, there are plenty of resources  online - you just have to search for them.

Comment: first thanks, but my database I  create using  MS Access not using SQL

Comment: If anyone have PDF ,or  good code how to connect database using (MS Access) to matlab

Comment: Access databases support SQL queries via the Microsoft Access Driver that you are loading in the connection string. You need to write an SQL query to get at your data.